# Not able to receive tcp(mode is server) message on channel with undefined terminator

Tags: java, spring, sockets, tcp, spring-integration

Currently we are using Spring Integration 2.1.0 Release(Due to legacy application can not switch on latest version ) in our application. 
Application flow is as below:

1. All the configuration details are defined in a configuration file, like host name, port number, terminator etc
2. Get the message from TCP using tcp-inbound-channel-adapter via channel.
3. Pass it to splitter for further flow.

Here issue is if message has terminator other than, which is defined in configuration file,message does not come to class defined for splitter, if terminator is same, it is working fine.
Requirement is if terminator value is different it should show a error message on same channel using tcp-outbound-channel-adapter(inbound and outbound is used due asynchronous call).
 I have enabled the application and spring logging at Trace level but not able to understand why and where message is stuck.

Code for Configuration file is

```
<Config>
<host>localhost</host>
<port>8888</port>
<mode>server</mode>
<terminator>10</terminator>
<msgLength>65535</msgLength>
<inChannel>telnetInboundCustomChannel</inChannel>
</Config>
```

XML for connection details

```
<beans:bean id="serverCustomSerializer"
class="com.core.serializer.CustomSerializer">
<beans:property name="terminatingChar" value="${server.terminator}"/>
<beans:property name="maxLength" value="${server.msgLength}"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="serverFactoryTaskExecutor"   
class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
<beans:property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
<beans:property name="queueCapacity" value="0" />

</beans:bean
<int:channel id="telnetLandingChannel" />
<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverFactory" type="server"
host="${server.host}" port="${server.port}" single-use="false"
serializer="${server.serializer}" deserializer="${server.serializer}" task-
executor="serverFactoryTaskExecutor"/>

<ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="serverInboundAdpater"
channel="telnetLandingChannel" connection-factory="serverFactory"
error-channel="errorChannel" auto-startup="false"/>
<ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="serverOutboundAdapter"
channel="serverReplyChannel"
connection-factory="serverFactory"
auto-startup="true"/>
```

XML for Channel details and flow are:

```
<int:channel id="telnetInboundCustomChannel" />

<int:splitter id="messageSplitter"
input-channel="telnetInboundCustomChannel" ref="telnetCustomMessageSplitter"
method="splitCustomMessageStream" 
outputchannel="base24CustomSplitterChannel" />

<int:filter id="messageFilter" input-
channel="base24CustomSplitterChannel"
output-channel="base24CustomCoreMessageChannel" 
ref="telnetCustomMessageFilter"
method="customMessageFilter" />
<!--Other code to get data from filer and pass it to correct router -->
```

If somehow message is visible in filter class, I can apply the logic to written error code on TCP connection.
I have applied the break points on run() of TcpNetConnection class as well. I am not able to understand Spring Integration internal flow. How message is coming even till splitter. 
I have noticed one more thing if I send message with correct terminator, after sending with wrong terminator, Spring will append new message with old message.

Looks like without correct terminator spring is not able to cut the frame and it is stuck in telnetInboundCustomChannel.
Please guide how to fix this issue and reason of issue for better understanding.

Comment: The requirement is strictly meaningless. There is no such thing as a message in TCP, and no such thing as a message with an undefined terminator in any protocol.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you can detect a bad terminator. By definition the deserializer needs to know a message is complete before returning. You could detect a socket close  (bite < 0) and n>0 and return a special message but I don't see how else you can emit a message unless you know what invalid terminator(s) to look for.

**EDIT**

If you mean check for another "special" (non-printable) character, then you can use something like...

```
if (n > 0 && (bite == bytes.byteValue())) {
    break;
}
else (if bite < 0x20) {
    return ("Bad terminator for" + new String(buffer, 0, n)).getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Definition of bad terminator/undefined terminator is, when terminator value does not match with the value defined in Configuration file. For Example value of terminator is 10 (<terminator>10</terminator>), if message ends with any other byte like 9/11/12... splitter class is not able to listen it. Control is neither coming to CustomSerializer class. Not able to understand where it is going.

Comment: Not able to findout any code in application which is preventing the message. Does spring requires any terminator to know that message completed and it can be send to its listener?

Comment: But what if the "bad terminator" is "z" ? How can you possibly know that the message is complete unless you have some known condition that the client and server agree on? If you just mean special chars < 0x20, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately control is not coming on customSerializer . In normal flow first it used to land-on on  telnetCustomMessageSplitter. Serialize and deserialize method is called when we route the message over ActiveMQ. Not able to find out any other class before calling of  telnetCustomMessageSplitter.  Does Spring calls any call after receving message from TCP socket and before putting that message on channel (telnetInboundCustomChannel).

Comment: @PrabhjotSokhi What message? TCP is a byte stream, not a message-passing protocol. You don't know you've got a message *until you have the correct terminator*, if it's a terminator-based protocol. All this talk of 'message with an undefined terminator' is completely and utterly meaningless.

Comment: Exactly, the bottom line is the sender and receiver have to agree how to determine what constitutes a "message" within the stream. If the sender doesn't honor that agreement, in Spring Integration terms, the deserializer will wait forever (or until the socket times out if a timeout has been set). You could catch that timeout in your deserializer and return a "partial" message, but that would be a very brittle architecture since network glitches could cause spurious message emission. You HAVE to fix the sending side.

Comment: Thanks Gary and EJP, shared the technical challenge with client, somehow it was working in .net, that's why exception was same here as well. Communicated to them either message should be of fixed length or it should have same terminator.

Comment: Or a length word prefix, or a type-length-value protocol, or a self-describing protocol, or, ... but it must in in the application protocol. Whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is strictly meaningless. There is no such thing as a message in TCP, and no such thing as a message with an undefined terminator in any protocol.